# Python - datetime of a specific timezone

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I am having the hardest time trying to get the current time in EDT timezone.

```
print datetime.time(datetime.now()).strftime("%H%M%S")
```

datetime.now([tz]) has an optional tz argument, but it has to be of type datetime.tzinfo... I have not ben able to figure out how to define a tzinfo object for Eastern timezone... Seems like it should be pretty simple, but I cant figure it out without importing an additional library.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am not very conversent about the EDT time zone but this example should serve your purpose.

```
import datetime
```

datetime.datetime.now must be passed the time zone info which should be of type datetime.tzinfo. Here is a class that implements that with some of the required functions. I am providing no day light saving details here as this is an example.

```
class EST(datetime.tzinfo):
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
      return datetime.timedelta(hours=-5)

    def dst(self, dt):
        return datetime.timedelta(0)
```

Now you could use this to get the info with time zone correctness:

```
print datetime.datetime.now(EST())
```

Output:

```
2010-11-01 13:44:20.231259-05:00
```

Comment: thanks - frustrating you have to create a whole class to specify a timezone (vs just passing a simple variable)

Comment: @wuntee: Thats not true. This was meant as an explanation. The answer by adw contains the library - pytz which can be used to pass tzinfo information. It fact that would be reuse and aspects like dst etc are already provided by pytz module.

Answer (score 8):

The [`tzinfo`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects) class only defines an interface, you will need to implement it yourself (see the documentation for an example) or use a third-party module which implements it, like [`pytz`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/).

**Edit**: Sorry, I missed that you don't want to import another library.

Comment: +1 for providing pytz module as I was focused on explaining the tzinfo.