# Passing est datetime to MySql

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

In MySql db there is column of type DATETIME. I need to select the records by this column -- ones that are less than current est date. I used the code from [Python - datetime of a specific timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071924/python-datetime-of-a-specific-timezone) to determine the est date:

```
import MySQLdb
import datetime

class EST(datetime.tzinfo):
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
      return datetime.timedelta()

    def dst(self, dt):
        return datetime.timedelta(0)


def get_est():
    return datetime.datetime.now(EST())
```

Here is a select request:

```
a = 'SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Date <= %s' % get_est()
print a
cursor.execute(a)
data = cursor.fetchall()
for item in data:
  print item
```

At this point, I have an error of:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 2013-05-04 13:23:21.776521+00:00' at line 1")
```

How do I get rid of it? Notice that I have to use the current `est` datetime and pass it to sql request.

```
select * FROM Table1 WHERE Date <= '2013-05-04 13:34:03.461407+00:00'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your date values are not in quotes.

```
a = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Date <= '%s'" % get_est()
```

(I don't know python so I apologize if my syntax is incorrect.)

Comment: Can you post what your final query looks like?